# How to Update SimplePie

Tags: rss, simplepie

The installed SimplePie is outdated. I need the current version.
The directory and files in WordPress are different, so I don't know if I can just overwrite the files with the current SimplePie.org's version.

How can I update SimplePie that WordPress installs?
And, keep the updated version if WordPress updates itself?

Comment: The SimplePie version on my WP 4.3.1 install is 1.3.1. What SimplePie version do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

SimplePie for a long time is not truly an independent project as it was fully assimilated into wordpress. Not sure that there is any new development for it, but if there is it is unlikely to be any different than what it is at the latest wordpress core.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is [supposed to be resolved](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36669) in WP 5.4 (March 2020 delivery).

Meanwhile, this plugin may provide a temporary fix: https://github.com/michaeluno/_fix-simplepie-errors